# How to add custom build behavior in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, build, makefile, target

I often need to add in C/C++ Eclipse project some custom build commands, for example: make install, make test or make check and set a hot key for them. How to do this in Eclipse?

Or somebody can recommend me more appropriate IDE for this issue? I just need some additional make commands, along with build and clean.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create your own build commands in Eclipse go to `project / properties / builders / new` and you should be able to add your own builds.

If you want to create short cut keys for your make files you can try:
`Window / Preferences / General / Keys` and then look for `Run And Build`.